# Parse Push Notification iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I had the Push thing done over with at [Parse.com](http://parse.com) (It was working and all) and then I was asked to create an account on parse for the company and set them up so they can manage it on their own. Well, not realizing that there was a Export button on the website, I deleted the app on my account and created an account for them and added the app to their account. I added all of the correct Certs and updated the App and Client keys and it wouldn't send it,and  On the Push Notifications tab, it will show that i have recipients (My test Devices) but when I hit send, it will say Done, but nothing will appear on my device. So, being not too smart, I deleted that app and recreated it on my account (Thinking there might be something wrong with the other account). Well now it won't even work on my account. I have created all new certs and everything and i can't figure out why it is not working.And again, On the Push Notifications tab, it will show that i have recipients (My test Devices) but when I hit send, it will say Done, but nothing will appear on my device.  Help?

My thought about what it might be is that the device is remembering the APNS Permission from the old account, Could I be Right?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, am tearing my hair out last day or so, have repeated the process about 10 times now. Keep me posted if you have any joy and I will do the same!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this a while back.  For me it was the difference between developer builds and release builds.  You'll see in Apple's provisioning portal that there are 2 push certificates you can set up for your app.  One is for production release and the other is for developer testing.  When you build your app for testing it automatically looks for the developer cert.  When you do a release build it looks for the release cert.

So... Make sure you have uploaded the correct push certificate to Parse.  In my case Parse would say that messages had been sent to devices but I never saw them come through because Parse was sending them to Apple with a certificate that did not match my particular build type.

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get a chance.

Comment: IT WORKED, I WOULD GIVE YOU THUMBS UP IF I HAD ENOUGH REP. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: @Dancreek Can we add both production and development p12 certificates in Parse dashboard? If it was development (debug) or if it was release both are supported?

Comment: @Maziyar Not last I checked.