# Parse push notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, parse-platform

Integrated [parse](https://www.parse.com/) push notification in iOS project. Not working.

Here is my code:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_PARSE_PUSH
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#endif

//in appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

#ifdef ENABLE_PARSE_PUSH

    // Obtain the installation object for the current device

    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID clientKey:PARSE_APP_SIGNATURE];

    PFInstallation *myInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    // Save some data
    [myInstallation setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"scoreUpdates"];

    // Save or Create installation object
    [myInstallation saveInBackground];

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
#endif



#ifdef ENABLE_PARSE_PUSH
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken]; // Send parse the device token
    // Subscribe this user to the broadcast channel, ""
    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded)
        {
            //#ifdef DEBUG
            //NSLog(@"Successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            //#endif
        }
        else
        {
            //#ifdef DEBUG
            //NSLog(@"Failed to subscribe to the broadcast channel.");
            //#endif
        }
    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}

#endif
```

here is one [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260273/parse-push-notification-ios) not helped for me..tried all suggested solutions. What's wrong..already uploaded development push SSL in parse.com. help me to get solution.

Now test push message from parse.com is not delivering in device.

Comment: no solution without the problem description. "Not working" can mean anything.

Comment: when I send push message from parse.com then It is not delivering to any device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Finally resolved this problem.

• We need to create new provisioning profile after configuring push SLL in app id section. Then we need to use new provisioning profile.

This solved my problem and now getting test push message from Parse.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Have you try this Parse step by step Tutorial 
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Follow the tutorial and if you get stack you can post here for help .

Comment: exactly same link I followed while integration...double checked now...no use

Comment: few things to check , is your app saving the installation key on the database ?  you need to find the problem , try NSlog to get some feedback ..

Comment: not used key while exporting SSL certificate...worked for one of my other project..same code not working in this...strange